# How do I finalize a data CD on Windows XP?

Tags: windows-xp, burning, compact-disc

I've just burned a data CD on Windows XP.  I want to finalize it so it can no longer be written to.  What are my options?

There don't seem to be any options for finalizing when I eject the disk.

Answer (score 4):

1. Download and run **[InfraRecorder](http://infrarecorder.org/)**
2. Insert your disc into the drive
3. Go to **Actions** > **Fixate Disc**. This will write lead-out information to prevent further data from being added to the disc

   [image]

InfraRecorder is free, open source and portable.